# How to initialize "hasil" so i can use it in switch function?

Tags: java, if-statement, switch-statement

I'm making a program to sum your grades and bases on that determine to which class you belong to using if and switch. But i can't seem to make the if statement work to the switch statement. The Error said "java variable hasil might not have been initialized"

I've tried using if else and switch

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.stream.*;
public class Tugas1 {
    public static void main(String[]args){
        int hasil;
        float rata2;
        System.out.println("Input berapa kali anda ujian : ");
        Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);
        int n=input.nextInt();
        int[] array1 = new int[n];
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++) {
            System.out.println("Nilai ujian "+(i+1)+" :");
            array1[i] = input.nextInt();
        }
        int sum=IntStream.of(array1).sum();
        rata2=sum/n;
        System.out.println("Jumlah nilai anda : "+sum);
        System.out.println("Rata-rata nilai anda : "+rata2);
        if (rata2<=60) hasil=1;
        else if (rata2<=70) hasil=2;
        else if (rata2<=80) hasil=3;
        else if (rata2<=90) hasil=4;
        else if (rata2<=100) hasil=5;
        switch (hasil){
            case 1:
                System.out.println("Anda masuk kelas A");
                break;
            case 2:
                System.out.println("Anda masuk kelas B");
                break;
            case 3:
                System.out.println("Anda masuk kelas C");
                break;
            case 4:
                System.out.println("Anda masuk kelas D");
                break;
            case 5:
                System.out.println("Anda masuk kelas E");
                break;
            default:
                System.out.println("Anda tidak masuk kelas apapun!");
        }

    }
}
```

I expect the output,for example, if rata2 is <=60 then hasil=1 and the output is "Anda masuk kelas A"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`hasil` is being intialized in `if` condition so if no `if` or `else if` condition met and in your case`else` is also missing there that's the reason you are getting this error

so either intialize it with some default(`hasil=0`) value or intialize `hasil` inside `else`